# Why datepicker doesn't display in my MVC 3 Website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, datepicker

I'm following this [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx) to display a datepicker when I click into a textbox... But the date picker doesn't display...

**Model Class (Reservation):**

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date requise.")]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [Column("Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

**EditorHookup.js**

```
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" />
/// <reference path="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" />
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
});
```

**Partial View (Date.cshtml)**

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.DateTime?>
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
              new{@class="date"})
** TODO Wire up the date picker! **
```

**My view**

```
@model TennisOnline.Models.Reservation

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/EditorHookup.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Reservation</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
    </div>
```

So, do you know why the date picker doesn't display please ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your partial view model is not called because the DataType of your property is wrong. Replace

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
```

with

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
```

and everything should work as intended.

**Edit**

You should also remove the `@inherits`line from your partial view as inherits is not allowed with model.

Comment: After that, I catch an HttpParseException :The 'inherits' keyword is not allowed when a 'model' keyword is used.

Comment: At least now you know your partial view is called. You're making progress! You should get rid of the @inherits line. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Thank you I remove the @inherit line... But I have a new exception now sorry :( ==> InvalidOperationException :The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'.

Comment: you should return from your controller something like return View(new Reservation { Date = DateTime.Now });

Comment: I'm sure that the controller works done...The exception occurs when I click into the Action Link "reservation", and the exception is pointing over the line :  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date)

Comment: You can allow for a null value by having your model be a Datetime? (nullable) instead of a Datetime

Comment: Thank you for the response and your patience ! I change DateTime by a DateTime? nullable but I still have the same exception. It's strange

Comment: It works ! return View(new Reservation { Date = DateTime.Now }); You had right !

Answer (score 2):

I think your view is missing a reference to the ="~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" script.

Comment: Thanks, I add the reference but my problem persists :(

Answer (score 0):

I think your partial view may need to be named DateTime.cshtml to match the type of your model property.